# C# code refactor (lambda expression)

Tags: c#

I am trying to verify that there is a file with a certain filename in a zip file. Is there a better way to do it than the following?

```
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFilePath))
        {
            if (!archive.Entries.Any(e => e.Name.Equals(FileNameToCheckFor)))
            {
                // Throw an exception
            }

            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
            {
                // Do some processing. This is unrelated.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Looks perfectly OK to me. Except I prefer to use `var` instead of the type name in the `using` for example: `using (var archive = ...)`

Comment: That seems pretty reasonable except that you're enumerating the list of entries twice. If there's a way to better organize your work you could probably avoid that. The importance of this is dependent on the size of the zip files as ripping through a 2PB Zip file twice is probably a bad idea...

Comment: @Chris surely the zip format has an index of files at the start..

Comment: What about this instead?
if (archive.GetEntry(ExportFileName) == null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [ZipArchive.GetEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.getentry.aspx) returns null if the entry does not exist, you could replace the lambda expression with:

```
 if (archive.GetEntry(FileNameToCheckFor) == null)
 {
      // Throw an exception
 }
```

This is slightly more concise, but that is not to imply anything incorrect about the original code.